# npm http and syntax explaination

Tags: javascript, http, server

I need some clarification on some the syntax below and the order of the code that is being executed.

I am guessing it first starts with the creation of the server

`var server = http.createServer(handleRequest);`

and then the `server.listen` function gets executed.

But on the browser, when the user ends on a path such as `'/'`, from where is the `handleRequest` function being invoked from and also what returns and gets stored in `var server`. And is the `.listen` part in `server.listen` part of the `npm http` package just like `createServer` is?

```
// Here we require/import the HTTP module
var http = require("http");

// Here we define a port to listen to
var PORT = 8080;

// Here we create a generic function to handle requests and responses
function handleRequest(request, response) {

  // The below statement is triggered (client-side) when the user visits the PORT URL
  response.end("It Works!! Path Hit: " + request.url);
}

// Here we use the Node HTTP package to create our server.
// We then pass it the handleRequest function to empower it with functionality.
var server = http.createServer(handleRequest);

// Here we start our server so that it can begin listening to client requests.
server.listen(PORT, function() {

  // The below statement is triggered (server-side) when a user visits the PORT URL
  console.log("Server listening on: http://localhost:%s", PORT);

});
```

Comment: I know this doesn't answer the question, but the `http` module is a built in module of the Node core, it's not necessary to install it with npm

Answer (score 0):

The `HTTP` module is module built in to Node directly. `createServer()` returns a server instance which has a method called `listen`. This essentially sets up an event listener for the `request` event. When an incoming request comes in, HTTP directs it to the `handleRequest()` function

Answer (score 0):

`http` is a part of node ([docs](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html)), just not loaded by default so we you have to require it.

`var server = http.createServer(handleRequest)` makes a new `http.Server` instance, sets the variable `server` to reference that instance it just made, and tells it to route any requests to the function `handleRequest`.

`server.listen(PORT)` uses that created http.Server instance and call's its listen method with the port of whatever `PORT` equals, telling `server` to listen to the specified port. So `.listen` is a part of the `http` module

Whenever `server` gets a request, like you go to http://localhost:8080/ it calls `handleRequest` with two parameters, the first is the request and the second is the response we can write to. `handleRequest` takes the url from the request parameter it's given, then writes to the response parameter a string plus the url and ends the response which effectively sends the response.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. It is beginning to be more clear. When the handleRequest function is being passed as a parameter to http.createServer, it becomes a property of that instance as servers as a callback function I am guessing, so that whenever a request is made, the call back function handleRequest is invoked?

Comment: @ANonymous As you said, `handleRequest` is like a callback, it is async. So the server waits for a request, then whenever a request is made to that server instance, it calls the `requestListener(requestData, responseData)` (note requestListener is from the docs [http.createServer docs](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_createserver_requestlistener). requestData and responseData are just random names to signify the data is calls the function with) which is `handleRequest` in this scenario.